# how to remove a unneeded namespace declaration from xml element with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

A maybe easy question about supressing unwanted namespace declarations.

```
  <table xmlns:new="http://ns.namespaces4all.com/xmlcombine/new"    
   xml:base="file:///R:/example/Sample.xml" frame="all">
    <tgroup cols="2">
        <colspec colname="c1"/>
        <colspec colname="c2"/>
        <tbody>
          <row>
            <entry>
              <m:math xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
              <m:mrow>
                 <m:mi>x</m:mi>
```

I just want to drop the not needed namespace **xmlns:new** and I want to keep **xmlns:m**, but *exclude-result-prefixes="new"* or *extension-element-prefixes="new"* remove that.
What else is possible to suppress that?
Best regards

Markus

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete example of your XML and XSLT (+ indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0).

Comment: Why would you need something else than `exclude-result-prefixes`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller `exclude-result-prefixes` will not remove unused namespace declarations when elements carrying them (or their descendants) are copied.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, then `copy-namespaces="no"` might help - but we don't know yet...

Comment: @MathiasMüller In XSLT 2.0 it would.

Comment: The user asked the same question on the Saxon support forum, again without posting source code, and it emerged in due course that the namespace was indeed being copied from the source document rather than the stylesheet, so copy-namespaces="no" should be the answer.

Comment: when I will use copy-namespaces="no" the template will also remove the MathMl Namespace. @MichaelKay: Sorry for postig that twice.

Comment: If you can find a way to output an element in the MathML namespace without outputting a declaration of the MathML namespace, with the XML output method, that's a bug. Please post a bug report with a self-contained test case for it.

Answer (score -1):

hope this helps,

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                version="1.0">
```

Use this exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" to specify which namespaces you don't need

Comment: `exclude-result-prefixes` was already mentioned in the question. The question is: "What else is possible to suppress that?" (even if I have no clue why the OP is asking it). Also, you should at least modify the random code snippet to exclude `xmlns:new` and not `xmlns:msxsl`.